# Verifying schematic idea: circuit design for MOSFET driven by ESP32

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, inrush-current, esp32

I have an ESP32 that I will use to drive open a solenoid valve.

The MOSFET I will use is an IRLZ44N, which is best operated at 5 V (I think that the 3.3 V voltage, although is above the V<sub>gs(th)</sub>, will be insufficient).

My circuit therefore uses 3 voltages: `3.3 V` generated by the built-in regulator, and `5 V` and `12 V` provided by a PC power supply.

I read on some forums that at a high frequency the MOSFET's capacitor can damage the IO pin with the inrush current.

Because I will use the PWM of the ESP32 at about 500 Hz in order to lower the power consumption of the valve I am afraid that I could fry the pin used.

**This is the circuit I came up with:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAtbTi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- R2 is the valve which draws about 5 W
- Q1's base is pulled up by R4 so that the MOSFET is not conducting when the MCU is initializing. The collector current should be limited to 80 mA which is lower than the absolute 100 mA for this BJT.
- R1 is an "artifact" from the time when the MOSFET's gate was directly connected to the IO pin. I am not sure if it would do anything in this circuit as the power supply is pretty beefy and thus should be able to handle the inrush current.

My aim is to use as few resistors as possible without the risk of burning the ESP32. Is this circuit safe even without that R1? Will discharging the gate capacitor through the BJT at the PWM frequency affect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that the 3.3V voltage, although is above the Vgs(th), will be insufficient.

Nope, you're wrong. For a 5W load with V<sub>DD</sub> = 12V, the drain current will be around 400mA. If you check the transfer characteristics from the datasheet then you'll see that V<sub>GS</sub>=3.3V is quite sufficient I<sub>D</sub> = 500mA.

Here's a circuit you can use:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi8N4H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 should be selected so that the signal at the gate of M1 should not be completely chopped off as R1 and M1's C<sub>iss</sub> form a first-order LPF. For f<sub>PWM</sub> = 500Hz in your case, you can select f<sub>C</sub>=5kHz:

$$
\mathrm{f_c = (2\pi\ R1\ C_{iss})^{-1}  \\ 
\rightarrow 5kHz = (2\pi\cdot R1\cdot 1.7nF)^{-1} \\
\therefore R1 = 18k (max)}
$$

I selected R1 = 1k for proper operation with lower duty cycles.

D1-R2 couple guarantees a faster turn off for the MOSFET.

---

If you really worry about the ESP's IOs then you can use a totem-pole output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiIoJu.png)</sup>

Comment: Without R2 and D1 could I still use the mosfet with 50% duty at 500Hz?

Comment: @sergiureznicencu yes, but I'd keep them anyways.

Comment: If I were to power 5 mosfets from 5 different pins at the same time do you think this would overpower the mcu? For the inrush current: 3.3/1000 *5=16.5mA (the current adds up somewhere in the mcu right?)  ?

Comment: If you place a single totem-pole and feed the MOSFETs from it (with individual series resistors, of course) then there'll be no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few points and pointers:

Without R1, what would be limiting the current through Q1? R1 is the pull-up for the FET's gate.

I think the IRF530 can take 12 V V<sub>GS</sub>, look it up, if that is true, there is no need for a separate switching voltage.

The IRF530 will probably conduct well enough for this load at V<sub>GS</sub> = 3.3 V, you can look that up, and if true, there is no need for Q1.

***Don't forget to put a diode across the (inductive) load.***

Otherwise, see other answer.

Comment: I think you meant IRLZ44N not IRF530.

Comment: True I didn't notice that small "short" circuit through R1

Comment: I didn't look beyond the IRF530 in the schematic.

Comment: I now fixed the label. Thank you